# Postman api key not valid in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, postman, gitlab-ci-runner

In my gitbal-ci.yml using the below instruction:

```
curl -s https://api.getpostman.com/environments?apikey=${POSTMAN_APIKEY}
```

I receive the error:

> ```
> error: could not load environment
>   Invalid API Key. Every request requires a valid API Key to be sent.
> ```

The variable POSTMAN_APIKEY is correctly set in my gitlab Setting CI/CD as POSTMAN_API with the key generated in my postman account.

If I try to execute the curl command via shell, it works perfectly.
What's wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use double quotes `"curl -s https://api.getpostman.com/environments?apikey=${POSTMAN_APIKEY}"` because of variable expansion in bash. But variable name must be the same in Setting CI/CD, so `POSTMAN_APIKEY` in both places. If you set variable as protected, be sure to flag your branch as protected as well.

Comment: Still same problem...

Comment: even with `curl -s https://api.getpostman.com/environments?apikey="${POSTMAN_APIKEY}"`